# systemd start mariadb after mounting USB stick

Tags: debian, systemd, mariadb

I moved the datadir of mariadb to a USB-stick, subsequently mariadb won't start anymore at boot time, because the stick is mounted after mariadb was started. I tried to modify the start order by adding

```
[Unit]
After=remote-fs.target local-fs.target
```

to `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/tp.conf`, but it does not work. What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it according to [this Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247547). I had to write:

```
[Unit]
After=mnt-btrfs.mount
```